# What are the current travel restrictions in Vietnam?

Tags: air-travel, vietnam, covid-19, vietnam-airlines

I am planning to travel to Hanoi from Tokyo in the beginning of April for a couple of days. But news websites like [this](https://vietnaminsider.vn/vietnam-imposes-quarantine-restrictions-on-people-arriving-from-s-korea-and-japan/) mention that travellers from Japan and South Korea will be quarantined on entry while some other websites say that travellers from both these countries have been barred to enter.

Is there any official or government source where such information can be verified?

Answer (score 4):

The [Timatic news feed](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news.htm) has a page dedicated to [coronavirus restrictions](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm). This information is provided by each national government to IATA so that airlines can verify passenger documents and eligibility to enter or transit any given country.

Currently for Vietnam the restrictions are:

> VIET NAM - published 19.02.2020
>
> 1. Passengers who have been in or transited through China (People's Rep.) in the past 14 days are not allowed to enter Viet Nam. This does not apply to passengers who travel for diplomatic or official purpose.
>
>    - This does not apply to nationals of Viet Nam.
>    - This does not apply to passengers who reside in Viet Nam.
> 2. Passengers who travel for diplomatic or official purpose will undergo a medical examination at the border before allowed to enter Viet Nam.

Comment: It doesn't mention any quarantine restrictions though. I think it's almost certain that if you travel from/transit through South Korea you'll be in quarantine for 14 days. If you're going for a 5 day trip there's no point in going then

Comment: @Prada If it does not mention a quarantine, then the government has not informed the airlines of a quarantine. The news article you linked to has a headline that says Vietnam has imposed a quarantine, but the actual story says that the health department has only proposed a quarantine, but it has not actually done so. It is a rather poorly written (and inaccurate) headline.

Comment: Is it standard operating procedure for airlines to know if the passengers will be quarantined once they reach the country? I thought the airlines are only supposed to confirm visa status and entry restrictions? You can check this news where Korean travellers were supposed to be quarantined but refused. https://ampe.vnexpress.net/news/news/vietnam-sends-back-south-koreans-refusing-to-be-quarantined-4060485.html

Comment: @Prada Yes, it's pretty standard. You can see that many other countries notified the airlines of quarantines in effect. In any case, it's not possible to tell from that news story if this quarantine is an official policy or just something related to suspension of flights from Daegu. You specifically asked for official or government sources; the news stories are very much unofficial, while Timatic's data is as close to official as you are likely to ever get (especially with Vietnam).

Comment: Got it! I'll still wait if anyone has a better answer

Comment: @Prada You should also keep checking that web page every day. They do update it with new information when they receive it.